# as good as he is at playing the guitar

Tags: meaning, concessives

a. As good as he is at playing the guitar, his brother is even better.

b. As good as he is at playing the guitar, his brother is bad.

Let us say we are talking about two brother who are musicians.

In (a), one brother is good at playing the guitar and the other one is better.

In (b), one brother is good at playing the guitar and the other one is bad.

Are the sentences (a) and (b) grammatically correct?

Do they make sense?

Comment: A is fine. But look at this: His brother is as bad at playing the guitar as he is good at it. Or: He's as good at playing the guitar as his brother is bad.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with (a).

For (b), your statement sounds awkward and a better way would be:

> While he is good at playing the guitar, his brother is bad.

Answer (score 2):

B draws a comparison, without which the brother isn't intrinsically bad.

*With* as good as he is at playing the guitar, his brother is bad *in comparison*.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is *grammatically* correct but it sounds a little awkward. If a second person (the brother) is to be introduced, the word "he" has to be emphasized:

"As good as **HE** is at playing the guitar, his *brother* is even better."

That sounds unnatural. Usually the focus is elsewhere:

"As good as he **IS** at playing the guitar, he *used* to be (or he *could* be) better."

"As good as he is at **PLAYING** the guitar, he can't *tune* it."

"As good as he is at playing the **GUITAR** he's even better on *piano*."

Your second sentence - "As good as he is at playing the guitar, his brother is bad" - isn't idiomatic. It needs to end with a *comparative*, such as 'better'. (Or, alternatively, "As bad as he is...his brother is worse.") It would then be similar to your *first* sentence, and my comments above would apply.

It's unusual to introduce a second person into this construction. We would probably say, "While/Whilst/Although he is good at playing the guitar, his brother is even better" or "...his brother is bad/awful/Lil Wayne."

Comment: I don't agree OP's second example isn't idiomatic. Consider *Listen to me, daughter! As much as you might want to marry your boyfriend, **it ain't gonna happen**!* That's the same basic construction. Both "complements" are straightforward assertions (with no *comparative* element), which effectively treat the preceding ***as... as*** construction as equivalent to ***Even though** [he is **very** good at playing the guitar | you might want to marry your boyfriend **very** much]*.

Comment: The first one is fine, but situational. If it answers someone saying, e.g., "Surely, he is the best at playing guitar!" it is entirely natural. It feels unnatural only when it's not a conversational transition from him to his brother.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As much as you might want to marry your boyfriend, I don't want to marry your boyfriend.

Comment: @Fumble Fingers: Your _As much as you might want to marry your boyfriend, it ain't gonna happen!_ sounds to me like a _**Much** as you might want to marry your boyfriend, it ain't gonna happen!_ with **As** tacked - misleadingly - on the front. I think the **as... as** construction _has_ an inbuilt comparative element, with the stresses I mentioned pointing out the thing we're comparing. In OP's 2nd example which word would you stress? It would have to be "he": "_As good as **he** is at playing the guitar, his brother is bad_" It sounds awkward to me. Happy to have my heels dug out though.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: I don't accept that including or not including initial ***as*** determines whether or not the assertion that follows should include an explicit "comparison". But I will just mention that (for me, at least) it's perfectly idiomatic to replace the second ***as*** by ***though*** (but *not if the first **as** is present*) with OP's "guitar" example, but that version somehow seems far less natural with my example: ***Much though** you might want to marry your boyfriend, it ain't gonna happen!*